# Android Gradle Error id not found

Tags: android

In my android application i had imported Module from GitHub https://github.com/IsseiAoki/SimpleCropView#download .But after sync my gradle i get error :

```
 Error:(21, 0) Plugin with id 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven' not found.
```

in added modules built.gradle file which is as follows.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 9
        versionName "1.0.8"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'

group = 'com.isseiaoki'
version = '1.0.8'
def siteUrl = 'https://github.com/IsseiAoki/SimpleCropView'
def gitUrl = 'https://github.com/IsseiAoki/SimpleCropView.git'
Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())

bintray {

    user = properties.getProperty("bintray.user")
    key = properties.getProperty("bintray.apikey")

    configurations = ['archives'] //When uploading configuration files
    pkg {
        repo = 'maven'
        name = 'SimpleCropView'
        desc = 'A simple image cropping library for Android.'
        websiteUrl = siteUrl
        issueTrackerUrl = 'https://github.com/IsseiAoki/SimpleCropView/issues'
        vcsUrl = gitUrl
        licenses = ['MIT']
        labels = ['android']
        publicDownloadNumbers = true
    }
}

install {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        pom {
            project {
                packaging 'aar'
                name 'SimpleCropView'
                url siteUrl
                licenses {
                    license {
                        name 'The MIT License (MIT)'
                        url 'http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT'
                    }
                }
                developers {
                    developer {
                        id 'isseiaoki'
                        name 'Issei Aoki'
                        email 'i.greenwood.dev@gmail.com'
                    }
                }
                scm {
                    connection 'https://github.com/IsseiAoki/SimpleCropView.git'
                    developerConnection 'https://github.com/IsseiAoki/SimpleCropView.git'
                    url siteUrl

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}
artifacts {
    archives javadocJar
    archives sourcesJar
}

task findConventions << {
    println project.getConvention()
}
```

Comment: Are you using Android Studio ?

Comment: Yes Android Studio 1.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This package is already available on jcenter repo, so instead of include by source code, add compile package name in dependencies block of your app's build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.0.8' 
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Your dependencies should look like

```
dependencies { 
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) 
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0' 
    compile 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.0.8' 
}
```

Comment: I already done it
Module Gradle:

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile files('libs/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3/json_simple-1.1.jar')
    compile 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.0.8'
    compile files('libs/jcifs-1.3.18.jar')
    compile 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.0.8'
    compile project(':simplecropview')

Comment: Remove SimpleCropView module from your project and remove compile project(':simplecropview')  and just have the compile 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.0.8'

Comment: Also remove all compile files('libs/***.jar') since compile fileTree(dir:'libs', include:'['*.jar']) already includes all jars inside of libs folder.